# Replace <img class="image"> with <span class = "image"> using YUI3 or Javascript, No jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, yui

Replace an image node with a span node so that:

```
<div class = "imageholder">
    <img class="image" src="#" title="image">
</div>
```

becomes

```
<div class = "imageholder">
    <span class="image" title="image"></span>
</div>
```

Would like to use YUI3, but just plain javascript will do too. No jQuery please!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".imageholder > img");

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className = span.title = "image";
    imgs[i].parentNode.replaceChild(span, imgs[i]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/he6QM/

Comment: thanks mate, just going to give this a quick test run in my page :)

Comment: @user1525612: I just corrected a mistake. Use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`.

Comment: mate that works great thanks, but the title and span classname won't always be 'title' :p  It needs to be whatever the title and class name of the img was. So if the img had class 'birds' and title 'seagulls' , then the new span has to have the same :)

Comment: @user1525612: `span.className = imgs[i].className;` and then the same with the title.

Comment: thanks mate you've been a great help, that is 100% what i was after :)